# Differing outputs from shell and python

Tags: python

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

bind_ip = 'ifconfig | grep -E -o [0-9.]{9} | head -1'

bindip = os.system(bind_ip)

print bindip
```

When I run the command in a regular bash shell it gives me:

```
10.0.2.15
```

When I run the python script it gives me:

```
10.0.2.15
0
```

I do not understand why the two outputs are different.  There's some deeper interaction that I'm not understanding.

Note: I am a beginner in the realm of programming. My code is probably not very elegant or efficient. Any tips you have for either or just learning programming in general is very helpful.  So far it just seems to be staring at a lot of google search results and man pages.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you running the script? "0" might be the exit code

Comment: Did you execute `print bindip` statement when you ran from shell?

Comment: The docs for `os.system` specify that the return value is the exit code of the command. This is why you are getting "0" -> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: I write it into a text file, save with .py extension and run it at the terminal as: python <script name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just the exit code. Look at this for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system